# How to hide a view in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

Forgive me if this question is too silly or already asked I googled a lot but I did't get the correct answer. I need to hide one of my view but how can i do that my current code is given below

```
var view = pointer.getPath('parentView.previewImageView');
view.set('IsVisible', false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work if you use `isVisible` instead of `IsVisible`. For example:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    hide: function() {
        this.set('isVisible', false);
        Ember.run.later(this, function() {
            this.set('isVisible', true);
        }, 1000);
    }  
});
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/6ddPQ/2/